# How do I make groups in 2.8?

Tags: groups, collections

In the Blender Guru Donut tutorial he made a sprinkle for a donut. He copied that sprinkle and made a smaller version of it. He <kbd>Shift</kbd> selected both and made a group with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. When I do the same it assigns both sprinkles into a collection. I have read that the layer system is redone completely. So when I make a group out of the two objects, is it the same as a group and where can I see that group?

Answer (score 10):

Groups and Layers in 2.80 were scrapped and merged into the same thing now for 2.8.
These things are called Collections.

Open an Outliner Editor. Click the "Display Mode" button in the header and select "View Layer" from the dropdown menu.
You can make a new collection by right-clicking and pressing "New".
[image]

Then you can rename your new Collection.

[image]

Then in the Properties Editor, you assign your collection to be simulated in a particle system.

[image]

Comment: You mean "groups and layers were scrapped in Blender 2.80". Blender 2.79 still has them.

Comment: Thanks for that

Comment: @metaphor_set It means they have been messed up into a single thing